# Laravel 5 select query turning my links into weird format

Tags: mysql, database, select, laravel, view

I have links saved in one of my DB tables and am performing a simple DB Select Where query with l5 using:

```
$meddURL = Media::select('url')->where('id', '=', $mediaID)->get();
```

which is working but for some reason it's messing with my link when I print it to any textbox/textarea in a view.

In the DB the link is stored as: http://examplelink.com/image1.png

But when printed in the view: [{"url":"http://examplelink.com/image1.png"}]

I'm not quite sure why it's turning my link into this weird format.

Comment: [{"url":"http://examplelink.com/image1.png"}] this is JSON Format.

Comment: please show me the code in your view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement `Media::select('url')->where('id', '=', $mediaID)->get();` will return a Collection of Media objects, each which contain a url property. When you try to display this in the view, it gets converted to the JSON you're seeing.

You either need to change it to:

```
// get the media object
$media = Media::select('url')->where('id', '=', $mediaID)->first();

// set the variable to the url attribute
$meddURL = $media->url;
```

or:

```
// just directly get the url value from the query
$meddURL = Media::where('id', '=', $mediaID)->pluck('url');
```